# loading images via ajax call and meanwhile show loader image

Tags: jquery, ajax

just starting to learn the Ajax() function within jquery. trying to make a widget where image loader will appear until the images are loaded from server.

I want to apply the same for all the images comes in these li's.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<style type="text/css">
    li { padding: 10px; }
    ul.imageList li .pics { height: 50px; width:50px; }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('document').ready(function() {
        $('#click').click(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $(".imageList li").html('<img src="http://deltaplanveter.ru/app/webroot/img/loader.gif" />');
            $(".imageList li").load('1.png');
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="images">
    <ul class="imageList">
        <li><img src="1.png" class="pics" /></li>
        <li><img src="2.png" class="pics" /></li>
        <li><img src="3.png" class="pics" /></li>
        <li><img src="4.png" class="pics" /></li>
    </ul>
    <a href="#" id="click">Show Images</a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Please check my live code here
http://jsfiddle.net/ylokesh/cZ6F7/

Thanks !
Lokesh Yadav

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your image `<img>` element is present with a defined `src` attribute, there won't be any ajax/lazy-loading because, most browsers will load `<img>` even if they are `:invisible`.

However, you can use do something like that:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('img').hide();//hide all the images on the page
});

var i = 0;
var interval=0;
$(window).bind("load", function() {
    var interval = setInterval("doThis(i)",100);
});

function doThis() {
    var images = $('img').length;
    if (i >= images) {
        clearInterval(interval);
    }
    $('img:hidden').eq(0).fadeIn(100);
    i++;
}
```

And use a css rules to show the loader:

```
#gallery li a {
    background: url("/images/ajax-loader.gif") no-repeat scroll 50% 50% #EEEEEE;
}
```

Example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cZ6F7/2/)

---

**Edit:**

If you want to use Ajax to load your image, then you can trigger your loader image on [Ajax Start event](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/).

It your work best if you use a global container with a modal loader for example, but can also works with your specific case.

Example:

```
var $loader = $('<div />').attr('id', 'loader');
var $spinner = $('<img />').attr('src', '/images/ajax-loader.gif')
    .attr('alt', 'Loading');
$loader.append($spinner);
$('body').children().last().after($loader);

$('body').ajaxStart(function() {
       $loader.show();
    }).ajaxComplete(function() {
       $loader.hide();
    });
```

And the according css:

```
 #loader {
    background:
        url("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.4/themes/ui-lightness/images/ui-bg_diagonals-thick_20_666666_40x40.png")
        repeat scroll 50% 50% #666666;
    display: none;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0.3;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
 }

  #loader img {
    left: 45%;
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
  }
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/hEMwq/)

Comment: thanks Boris, your code works for me. Can't we place $(ajax()) to fetch the images from server and then append the container with original image by removing the loader image'

Comment: Sure you can use Ajax to load your image, check my updated answer.

Comment: okay. I am trying google to find any relevant website to get idea for exactly.. how to implement this kind of scenario with Ajax.  If you have any website url which can provide some insight .. please share :)

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#loadingDiv').hide()  // hide it initially
      .ajaxStart(function () {
        //alert('started');

        $('#loadingDiv').show();
       })
      .ajaxStop(function () {
       //alert('stoped');

        $('#loadingDiv').hide();
    });

<span id="loadingDiv"><img src="images/ajax-loader.gif" alt="Loading..."></span>
```